# Error: Unrecognised selector, Warning: Class implemented in both

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, unrecognized-selector

I'm running into a **unrecognised selector** error as my App is resolving the wrong library when calling a method in runtime.

---

What:

- I'm using `Reachability` and a private framework, we'll say `FooLib`
- I get the following runtime warning - before the method is called

  > Class Reachability is implemented in both 
  >   `.../Frameworks/Reachability.framework/Reachability(0x106590d18)` and 
  >   `.../Frameworks/FooLib.framework/FooLib(0x10628d6b8)` 
  >   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`
- `FooLib` has no dependencies to `Reachability`, nor does its sub dependencies, nor does it mention the word Reachability ever.
- The memory pointer in the stack trace clearly resolving to `FooLib` when calling a `Reachability` function

  > *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10628d6b8'

---

Podfile

- Podfile configuration in both my `App`, and my `FooLib` have:

  > use_frameworks!

---

Attempts:

- Clean (Cmd Shift K)
- Clean (Cmd Opt Shift K)
- Deleted DerivedData folder
- [From this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634564/reachability-strange-issue?rq=1), Removed SystemConfig, Clean, Add SystemConfig, Build

---

Does anyone have an idea whats going on? Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: this error happen on building or running ?

Comment: if it happen during run time then use class with framework name FooLib

Comment: Do you have a _stack trace_, or only the error output from the runtime? Do you yourself call `reachabilityForLocalWiFi`, or who does so? If it's you - where do you call it (please show some code).

Comment: @ShauketSheikh this is happening during runtime, and I am calling Reachability class/framework directly.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen, good eye, its just the error output, not the stack trace per se. I call the method directly. Import the library at top of file, and call [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi]. Even a Cmd+Click will direct me to the correct documentation and classes within Xcode. As expected. Just run time it gets confused and doesn't know what Reachability is  - - and to answer your question - - it is called after viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is just a guess, I'll remove the answer if it turns out to be complete bullshit...

Apple deprecated - [and maybe just have removed](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/ReadMe_md.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-ReadMe_md-DontLinkElementID_11) - the method `reachabilityForLocalWiFi`.
So it could be that your pods just import *old* header files, which satisfy the compiler, but at runtime, the function does not exist anymore, hence the *unrecognized selector* exception.

You could just try the suggestions from the [linked Apple Readme.md](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/ReadMe_md.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-ReadMe_md-DontLinkElementID_11)

Nevertheless, it would be interesting to find out if this really is the reason, and why the podfiles "misbehave" in that way.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I haven't had the chance to play with it for much longer so I removed Reachability completely, but your comment the most reasonable explanation for it I've come across - - I'm going to chalk it up to Xcode/Podfile black magic.